# Identifying the UIStepper that triggered the event

Tags: ios, uistepper

In my view, I have two steppers that are both linked to this function

```
- (IBAction)stepperChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {
    int value = [sender value];

    printf("value: %d", value);
}
```

Is there a quick and easy way to identify which stepper triggered this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the stepper a tag and then check the value of the tag. You can set a tag in code or in IB.

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare a property as well, which I like more than tags myself:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIStepper *stepper1;

- (IBAction)stepperChanged:(UIStepper *)sender 
{
    if (sender == self.stepper1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Value of stepper1 is: %d",sender.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to declare the property as IBOutlet UIStepper *stepper1 so that you can assign it from your storyboard/NIB in IB

Comment: Maybe, but I don't use IBOutlets, so the code above is for my use case. Plus he didn't specify if it was for storyboard or not.